# Как убрать с изображения все пиксели, кроме черных и заменить их на белые, не используя OpenCV, с помощью Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, color, rgb

Хотелось бы заменить все цвета, кроме черного и ближайших оттенков черного(не серого), на белый, вне зависимости какие это цвета

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а pillow можно использовать ? https://habr.com/ru/post/491542/

Comment: Что угодно кроме OpenCV)

Comment: То есть как? Берете изображение, представляете его "чем угодно" и работаете. В чем проблема? В понимании "что такое изображение"?

Comment: Если быть конкретным проблема в том, что я в первый раз сталкиваюсь с подобной задачей и новичок в python, какие методы, какие функции, что такое изображение в том числе, все это для меня пока вопросы.

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко Ну посмотрите для начала код по ссылке, которую вам выше дали